# Should the client authenticate on every route?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, authentication, jwt

There's a JWT in localStorage.

Let's say the user goes to `app.com/accounts`.

The JWT is sent to the backend `app.com/api/accounts` for the data, and before it reached it, it get's checked in the authentication middleware.

**backend**

```
let authenticationMiddlewareBackend = (req, res, next) => {
    let token = req.headers.authorization;
    jwt.verify(token, "secret", (err, decoded) => {
        if (err) {
            res.status(401)
        } else {
            req.decoded = decoded;
            next();
        }
    });
};

app.all("/api/*", authenticationMiddlewareBackend);
```

Now this is ok. The question is, **should the client side also do this before reaching `app.com/accounts`?**

**client**

```js
async function authenticationMiddlewareClient(next) {
    if (window.location.pathname != "/login") {
        let verifyResponse = await (
            await fetch(`/verify`, {
                method: "GET",
                withCredentials: true,
                credentials: "include",
                headers: {
                    Authorization: localStorage.getItem("token"),
                    Accept: "application/json",
                    "Content-type": "application/json",
                },
            })
        ).json();

        if (verifyResponse.isAuthenticated) {
            next();
        } else {
            page("/login");
        }
    } else {
        next();
    }
}

page("*", authenticationMiddlewareClient);
```

**backend**

```js
router.get("/verify", async function (req, res) {
    try {
        let token = req.headers.authorization;
        jwt.verify(token, "secret", (err, decoded) => {
            if (err) {
                res.status(401)
            } else {
                res.status(200).send({ isAuthenticated: true, ...decoded });
            }
        });
    } catch (err) {
        next(err);
    }
});
```

Should the client just store the authentication outcome in a variable, instead of making verification requests each time? I am not sure if this can be exploited somehow.

Comment: I don't think it is needed every time. When an authenticated request fails with a 401 error the front end can understand the token is invalid / expired and then remove the token. So, no need to verify each time in my opinion.

Comment: I didn't quite get what you mean. Can you please clarify? I still need to send a request each time to check the validity.

Comment: I meant, when logging in the generated token may be stored in a local storage and be used for subsequent results without validating. (it may be a good idea to verify it on the first page load). After that no need to verify the token again because if any other request fail toy will get a `401` error. So, if a 401 error comes remove the token from local storage and redirect the user to the login page.

Comment: I see. My confusion is the fact that if someone puts a made up token that has the `isAuthenticated: true` property, they can gain access to the app. Also, how would I know it's the first page load?

Comment: Even if they add a fake token, then they can't do any actions, right. Also when they try to do an action (making a request to backend) you will redirect them to login because the fake token is discovered by the backend and sends a `401`.

Comment: Right. I am doing a double check for no reason, as the API call itself is the check. What happens when there is no API call, and the client route is simply text? They could gain access to that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218631/discussion-between-boredfromboredom-and-ivan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to check the token on the App load and not on each of the routers. The token will be checked by the backend API and you can verify by checking if the status code is 401.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for a separate API-call, as it doesn't add any security nor efficiency to the process. Simply check the JWT in the middleware before handling any data, just like you're doing in the first file.

Comment: To follow up: Why do you think you might need to do it separately?

Comment: I have no idea. I don't know how to restrict access to the app itself. Should I just check the token content for the `isAuthenticated` boolean before rendering routes? What stops someone from putting a fake token in localStorage to gain access to the app?

Comment: If the token is fake, then your middleware will know it. You have a secret in there, which NOONE knows (hopefully), so they can't produce a sensible JWT that fits your secret

Comment: That's my question. *"If the token is fake, then your middleware will know it."* is saying that I still need to make a request to `/verify` backend route to check the validity, which is what I'm doing. The token is simply base64 and the middle part can be faked, as the client has no means to check the validity, without makind a request each time it needs to route.

Comment: No, but the middleware handles this, so you don't need to do it in a separate call. If a user wants to... post an image, but they need to be logged in: They post the image, with the JWT in the payload so that the backend can read it, verify the user's authorization, then send the image to the next part of the process. If you did this in a separate call, the user could simply fake the "success"-part on the client side, so it's better to do it in the middleware.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations. So you are saying that the act of getting the data can be the check. What about client routes that ask for no data, and are simply text i.e. no API call? How can I prevent access to that?

Comment: What kind of routes are these? Are you serving a server side rendered app? In that case the middleware is run no any routes you wish. If it's an API for a SPA, then you'll have to send some user-data down to the client, and limit it locally through your framework/js.

Comment: It's a SPA. *"then you'll have to send some user-data down to the client, and limit it locally through your framework/js"* can you please explain this? What do you mean?

Comment: Sorry, had a break. What I do in one of my SPAs is send the `user-level`with the authentication and the JWT, so that the client knows what things it should be able to show. Obviously it's doable to fake this variable, but even if you do, you won't be able to access anything "interesting" because anythign that is secret is fetched from the server, which requires a valid JWT.